# Why a string with containing a space and a number can be parsed to Date?

Tags: javascript, date-parsing

I'm working on a Date validation function for a custom render in my web app. When I get a string like "abc", what I do is try to parse it to Date using `Date.parse()` and it returns NaN since it's not parseable. The interesting part comes when I get a string containing some numbers separated as a token of the string (i.e. "abc 1"), the parse built-in method returns a timestamp. I don't understand why this happens. Does JS think it is a date format?

I try different strings to be parsed and it's curious:

```
Date.parse("abc") => NaN
Date.parse("abc1") => NaN
Date.parse("abc123") => NaN
Date.parse("abc 1") => timestamp
Date.parse("abc 123") => timestamp
Date.parse("abc 123456") => timestamp
Date.parse("abc 1234567") => NaN
```

```
const isDate = string => !isNaN(Date.parse(string) /* returns timestamp */);

isDate("abc 123"); // returns true
```

If someone can tell me the reason why this happen and any suggestion on how to fix this issue without using an extra library (i.e. moment) would be great!

Comment: What timestamp do you get?

Comment: For the example provided, the number returned is -58285675404000

Comment: a quick read through the [relevant mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) says that basically Date.parse takes and returns pretty inconsistent values, and actually recommends using a date parsing library.

My question is why you're allowing users to enter random strings instead of using a date input. When you say "web app", it's kind of assumed you're targetting modern browsers, which means support for built in date inputs with built-in validaton is pretty broad.